# ORA-00903: invalid table name

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following database table:

```
CREATE TABLE pontaje
    (
    coda        NUMBER(4) REFERENCES angajati( coda ),
    data        DATE,           
    ore         NUMBER(3)   
    );
```

When I run the code :

```
SELECT coda, SUM(ore) AS totalore
FROM   pontaje,
GROUP BY coda
```

I get `ORA-00903: invalid table name`.

But I know the table exists because: `SELECT * FROM pontaje` works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT coda, SUM(ore) AS totalore
FROM pontaje                       -- << remove comma
GROUP BY coda
```

Answer (score 11):

Remove the comma after the table name.